# java class declaration

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java class declaration <T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633768/java-class-declaration-t)

Sometimes I've seen that java classes are created as follow,

```
  public abstract class ObjectPool<T> {
  private long expirationTime;

  private Hashtable<T, Long> locked, unlocked;

  public ObjectPool() {
    expirationTime = 30000; // 30 seconds
    locked = new Hashtable<T, Long>();
    unlocked = new Hashtable<T, Long>();
  }

  protected abstract T create();

  public abstract boolean validate(T o);

  public abstract void expire(T o);

  public synchronized T checkOut() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    T t;
    if (unlocked.size() > 0) {
      Enumeration<T> e = unlocked.keys();
      while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        t = e.nextElement();
        if ((now - unlocked.get(t)) > expirationTime) {
          // object has expired
          unlocked.remove(t);
          expire(t);
          t = null;
        } else {
          if (validate(t)) {
            unlocked.remove(t);
            locked.put(t, now);
            return (t);
          } else {
            // object failed validation
            unlocked.remove(t);
            expire(t);
            t = null;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // no objects available, create a new one
    t = create();
    locked.put(t, now);
    return (t);
  }

  public synchronized void checkIn(T t) {
    locked.remove(t);
    unlocked.put(t, System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}
```

[full code](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/objectpool.html)

here, what does `<T>` means and what is the purpose of it? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Generic in Java. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1):

Read what you link says.

It allows you to extend the class with a specific type.

Example:

```
public class JDBCConnectionPool extends ObjectPool<Connection> { .... }
```

Comment: I did Neal, but I didn't get it correct.

Answer (score 1):

it's part of a feature called [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)